Pascals Theorem
Is Pascal's Theorem for a hexagon inscribed in a circle equivalent to the following formulation?
Given six points on a circle, each point is connected to two other points that are not adjacent to it. The three intersection points of these connecting lines are collinear.
If there are differences or nuances between this formulation and the standard statement of Pascal's Theorem, I would appreciate an explanation.

This formulation is not Pascal's Theorem, though you could modify it to become equivalent or a weaker form.
See the diagram below with inscribed (non-convex) hexagon $CDEFGH$ built following your statement. Pascal's Theorem concerns the points $IJK$, formed by intersections of opposite sides, which are indeed collinear (red line.) But there are in general more than three points formed by intersections of the sides, and these other points, which would be included in the OP statement, are not part of the theorem.

If I unscramble the hexagon to become convex we see the usual form below:

To become equivalent to Pascal's theorem, your statement must first specify that the six points are joined in a single polygon. As an example, with the same arrangement of points in the top figure I could instead make two triangles $\triangle{CDE},\triangle{FGH}$ which would also satisfy the statement but would clearly not have any opposite sides in the diagram. Then you also need to modify the statement to be about opposite sides. But then are you at Pascal's Theorem. =)
Alternatively, you could have a weaker version that just says for some arrangement of a hexagon on a circle, 3 points of intersection are collinear.

Can you clarify what you mean by "your statement must first specify that the six points are joined in a single polygon "?

Thanks for your help! So the "key-observation" are opposite sites. Every point belongs to two sides, that's how we get the two connections from each point. But I still face some understanding problems, why don't we connect in the first diagram G with D, they are opposite?

@CalvinLin: e.g., in a linear arrangement of $CDEFGH$, the initial OP specification could be two triangles $CEG, DFH$ in which case there are no opposite sides etc.

@Julius: you have to be careful with non-convex polygons where the lines can be drawn in many ways. In a non-convex hexagon, the opposite side is the 3rd sequential side from a side, e.g., sides must be circularly $abcabc$. It's not necessarily about the point "opposite".

What is the definition of a point beeing opposite to annother point? Because how I understand it each point is opposite to 3 other points, because every point belongs to 2 sides... sry havent noticed your comment let me think about  it :)

@Julius You can take any 6 points in any order. Say we take $123456$, then we're looking at the intersections $12 \cap 45, 23 \cap 56, 34 \cap 61$. The opposite refers to the "exact" opposite that is 3 points away. Not just 2 or 4 points.

@Julius: Oh I think see what you're meaning. Sure, there are other points that can be joined, but that's taking you away from a polygon. $G,D$ are indeed opposite, and we are not considering diameters or diagonals here, we are talking about sides of a polygon extended. If you start considering all lines joining two sets of 3 points on a conic you are heading towards Pappus' theorem.

I think I understand now

But still how do I know from 12 \cap 45, 23 \cap 56, 34 \cap 61 which points to connect. I think I'm missing something really important maybe very fundemental :)

@Julius: the concept of opposite is inherent in the constructed polygon with even numbers of points. For any point, or side, there is a single point, or side, exactly cyclically halfway around the polygon. Calvin Lins statement is exactly right. What he is saying is label the 6 points, in any order, 1-6. Then join them like connect-the-dots. You will have a proper polygon, likely in a non-convex configuration. And the intersections in question are the sides he is indicating (and on my red lines).

I could connect every point in 3 possible ways from that how do I know which two to 2 to choose ( I could connect 1 with 4,5 and 3)

@Julius: not if you labeled them 1-6 and played connect the dots, there's only one correct shape to make

I tested it out, thanks a lot, finally I understood!   One last question, you have given in the inital answer two diagramms are both pascals theorem? Because the second one is a little different here opposite sites are extended and the 3 intersection point we get from that are on one line.

They are both Pascal's Theorem, with respect to the red line. In fact, they're the same hexagon, just with the points moved around. Once you get into non-convex polygons there are typically something like $\approx n!$ variations on the polygon, sometimes there are nice ways to prove every configuration, sometimes you can use a small number of cases, sometimes an author will simply assert it holds for all cases because the demonstrations get cumbersome and too numerous. Pascal's theorem holds for all configurations inscribed hexagons if opposite sides intersect (but... see projective geometry)

Thanks a lot for your time and your very instructive posts!
